# goagent server error, when run python uploader.zip uploader

Tags: python-2.7

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "uploader.zip/__main__.py", line 10, in <module>
  File "uploader.zip/__main__.py", line 5, in main
  File "uploader.zip/appcfg.py", line 27, in <module>
  File "../local/proxy.py", `enter code here`line 1686, in <module>
    class DNSServer(gevent.server.DatagramServer):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'DatagramServer'
Exception KeyError: KeyError(140338870835888 ,) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
```

what do I? I don`t know about python.thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try to change your

```
class DNSServer(gevent.server.DatagramServer):
```

to

```
class DNSServer(gevent.server.StreamServer):
```

at line 1686 (in your case) of file `local/proxy.py`.

Find more at [this link](http://www.wapblog.info/ubuntu-12-10-use-goagent-2-1.html).